# pgpointcloud backup fails due to a missing relation

Tags: backup, postgis, point-clouds

I'm trying to backup a schema of only pointclouds, I try to use the built in backup in pgadmin4 and I receive the following error. It complains that `ERROR:  relation "pointcloud_formats" does not exist` I test the `select schema, srid from pointcloud_formats where pcid = 1` query and it returns without issue. Any ideas?

```
pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "pc_0201507091159" failed: PQgetResult() failed.
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  relation "pointcloud_formats" does not exist
LINE 1: select schema, srid from pointcloud_formats where pcid = 1
                                 ^
QUERY:  select schema, srid from pointcloud_formats where pcid = 1
pg_dump: The command was: COPY pointcloud_99_526.pc_0201507091159 (id, pa) TO stdout;
```